# Unable to edit files in _www group on OS X

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, chmod, chown

I am using my MacBook as a local dev environment. In order to make the files publishable I had to give my web folder user and group of `_www:_www` using `chown`.

I'm using another account to log into my MacBook and it will not let me edit the files. I have also tried adding my user to `_www` group using the following command, but still no success.

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a myusername -t user _www
```

Comment: Can you post the exact permissions of the folders, i.e. do a `ls -la` listing?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x@ 12 _www    _www       408 Feb  5 09:40 Symfony

Comment: @jini: This folder isn't group-writeable (characters 5-7 are r-x, instead of rwx). As such, mysername:_www will not be able to modify your files. You should do `chmod -R g+w _www` using your _www user.

Answer (score 4):

Adding your user to the _www group isn't enough: the files must be group-writeable for the members of the group _www to modify the files.

You should use the _www user (or sudo) to modify the permissions of the files, as so:

```
chmod -R g+w _www
```

Comment: I did: sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a myusername -t user _www    I then did sudo chmod -R g+w Symfony    Now I am able to do what I needed to do. My permissions on the Symfony folder are: drwxrwxr-x     everything cool?

Comment: @jini: Yes. Things are OK. Given its a local setup it's OK with the last part being (r-x), i.e. everybody that has an account on your machine can read (and "open") the _www folder, but not write to it. In case security matters (i.e. on a public server), you'd want to make a `chmod -R o-r _www` (i.e. remove the reading privilege for "others", which means all the users that are not _www, nor part of the group _www).

Comment: @jini: Please accept this answer if it did the job, so that future users can see it more easily.