# How to make a local user be able to edit files created by _www user and group on OS X?

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod, chown

I'm using OS X Snow Leopard. I have a web application hosted locally in the web server folder with `_www` user and `_www` group.

I'm unable to edit those files with my local user, who is part of the group `admin`.

Comment: This one sounds familiar: [Unable to edit files on Macbook pro. Permission denied](http://superuser.com/questions/386809/unable-to-edit-files-on-macbook-pro-permission-denied)

Comment: So is the one above your question?

Comment: no I commented on it because it was very similar to mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option is to add your local user to the _www group ; that's what groups are there for. Being administrator doesn't mean you own other user's files. You could of course override this using sudo, but this is bad.

Bottom line: add your local user to the _www group and make the files in the web server folder group-writeable ( `chmod -R g+w /path/to/we/server/folder/` )

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/214311/114676) on how to add your local user to the _www group.

Comment: this doesn't work for files added in the future. If the default umask of _www is set to 022 all the future files will get 0644 permissions and the user will not be able to write the files even he is added to _www. Still looking for a way to set umask of _www to 002. On Linux there seem to be an easy way to achieve this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/444867/linux-setfacl-set-all-current-future-files-directories-in-parent-directory-to

But it's not working on Mac :(